# What is this film about a group of friends travelling with camcorders who encounter people whose faces were distorted?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I roughly remember a group of friends travelling with camcorders who kept seeing people who just stood there facing away from them, and when they saw their faces shaking so fast, their faces were distorted. Alien take over film. Not that old, 2010 maybe.

Comment: So, was the entire film in a "found footage" style?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our [guide on asking identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957).

Comment: The title instantly reminded me of "Chernobyl Diaries", although it didn't have any aliens in it.

Comment: TV Tropes has a page on [demonic head shake](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DemonicHeadShake), but it doesn't seem like much help here.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [There Are Monsters](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2977158/) from 2013?

A group of students are on what is essentially a road trip, making a film project. They set up interviews and use camcorders a lot, but as it goes on more and more people behave in the way you describe.

They stand still, often looking the other way, in places where you wouldn't expect someone to just stand. When they suddenly move, it's sometimes with a shaking effect, a rush, or showing smiles which are too large, with the focus being on their faces.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the way that they behave?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be *[The Phoenix Tapes '97](https://foundfootagecritic.com/the-phoenix-tapes-97-2016/the-phoenix-tapes-97-2016-review/)*?

> “The Phoenix Tapes ’97” is a found footage sci-fi/horror film with an anonymous writer, director, and cast. The film follows four friends on a weekend getaway who find themselves at the epicenter of what is now known as the “Phoenix Lights” incident. The Phoenix Lights incident is an actual mass UFO sighting that took place in the Phoenix, Arizona region on March 13, 1997.

I haven't seen anything about blurred faces, but it matches the friends filming on camcorders, and is about the right age.

### Trailer

Found with a search for `film "found footage" aliens camcorder friends`